# What compiler make with try-catch block

Tags: c#, .net, exception, compiler-construction

I wonder what CSC compiler make with TRY-CATCH block. For example what compiler will do with code like below?
Will compiler change base code to other form of C# code, before compilation to MSIL? Can I preview this code? What is rules of compiler to work with TRY-CATCH block?

```
try
{
    int x =45;
    var obj = new MyObject(++x);
    obj.MyMethod(1234, "qwerty");
    short result = x / obj.Function(x);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.Writeline(@"Something goes wrong :/");
}
```

Comment: Did you try compiling the code and then using ildasm on it? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Comment: ildasm.exe will show my MSIL code, I would like to see how compiler change this code

Comment: What do you mean by "for another C#"? The point of the compiler is to convert C# into MSIL... why would you *expect* try/catch to be representable in another form within C# which doesn't include try/catch?

Comment: For example when compiler optimalize C# code, it change one form code to another form of C#. This is what I mean as "another form"

Comment: What makes you think even that about optimization? There are very few aspects where the compiler has any reason to convert C# to C#... query expressions spring to mind, but not a lot else.

Comment: I just what code which be finally compile to MSIL

Comment: Well you can see what the final IL is. Why does it matter to you what the compiler internals are? Why would you expect that to stay the same between versions? Does it matter if it translates it into other C# or some completely different format?

Comment: @Jacek, you already have "code which be finally compile to MSIL" in your question. Internally compiler does not represent code as C#, it is just some sort of abstract syntax tree... You may be asking how compilers work but it would be offtopic (as "Dragon book" is written about it).

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov I think you have right, I should find answer in how compilers work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this article for details:

[Compiler Internals - How Try/Catch/Throw are Interpreted by the Microsoft Compiler](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/175482/Compiler-Internals-How-Try-Catch-Throw-are-Interpr)

Answer (score 4):

See here: http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2004/09/15/230167.aspx

A try-catch block actually looks very similar in IL as it does in source code. What exactly goes into IL depends on what you specify in source code; there are a couple of constructs, like `.fault` (which is like `finally` but only executes if an exception was thrown), that have no C#/VB equivalent, but the compiler can still identify lines of "common" error-handling code and put them in a single `.fault` block.

Answer (score 1):

try - catch is a concept which is completely analyzed during compile time and therefore won't have big impact at runtime.

Please checkout this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/175482/Compiler-Internals-How-Try-Catch-Throw-are-Interpr). It will surely help you.